# Git log not update file date modified

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, git-merge, git-branch

We generally work on two developer and master brunch

On developer rice, when friends make changes and make a reduction, when sending to the server, it says that the developer local branch should be confused with the developer remote branch.
Now in this chaos, he would change some files, for example, he would delete some of them and delete some of his changes.

Today I encountered this and saw that for example the whole folder or even the last modified file is returned to the previous

I was using the git log command, we see that it shows the old log and the new comets are no longer on the log

Also, when I checked from the site, we see that everyone is in history, but it seemed that the head was on the previous comma, it was running on the source.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cannot make much sense out of this question (due to language translation issues and/or typos) but I will note that in a commit, there are no *file dates*. The commit itself has *two* date-and-time stamps: an "author date" and a "committer date". The GitLab page picks one of these two dates to display. Rebase normally preserves the author date and replaces the committer date with the date-and-time provided by the computer's clock.